# Finding Specific Solution to Linear Diophantine Equation

Tags: chinese-remainder-theorem, euclidean-algorithm, linear-diophantine-equations

Other than by brute force, how can I solve $a=20k+91806$ to find the solution $a=96646$ (or $k=242$) if I know the following:

A. The prime factorization of $91806$ is $2,3,11,13,107$.

B. $GCD(a,91806)=22$.

C. $a\equiv 91806 \mod 20$

Is it possible to find that specific solution with the known information using the Chinese Remainder Theorem or some similar process?

EDIT: I noticed that $k=242$ for the solution I want. $242 = 11(GCD)$. Does knowing that $GCD(a,91806)=22$ somehow allow me to iterate $k$ by $22$ instead of by $1$ or is this just a coincidence?

Comment: Could you clarify the question? It's not even clear what you would brute force here... the solutions arise by plugging in any value of $k$

Comment: I'm basically trying to find that solution in less than 242 steps (the value of k I want). I noticed that 242 was 11*GCD but I'm not sure if knowing the GCD can reduce the number of steps in general (in this case from 242 to 11). Is there any shortcut to get to 96646 given the known info without having to try 242 values for k?

Comment: I understand, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition $\mathrm{gcd}(a,91806) = 22$ (in particular, $22 | a$) implies that $k$ is a multiple of $11$.

To make the gcd exactly $22$, there are some further requirements on $k$; for example, $k$ must not be a multiple of $3$; but incrementing $k$ by $11$ will find solutions rather quickly.

For example, there is a smaller solution to your conditions with $k = 11$ and $a = 92026$.

Comment: So if I know that a=20k+b and GCD(a,b)=22, then is it safe to say that a=440j+b (as long as the gcd is correct)? How is it known that k cannot be a multiple of 3?

Comment: @LamarV If $k$ were a multiple of $3$ then so is $a$; therefore, so is $gcd(a,91806)$.

Comment: Got it. I also noticed that I typed '440' instead of '220' in my prior comment. It should read a=220j+b. Thank you for your help!